# how to limit the number of inputs for the following code? c++

Tags: c++, c++11, conditional-statements

so basically this code below is nothing but three stores from which user buys guns. user has to press exit to get out of one store and go into other.

I want to put a limit on the user that he can overall buy only 10 guns collectively from all three sections.

For example, if the user buys 10 guns from the first store buying from the other stores process should be skipped then. And suppose if the user buys 6 guns from first store and 4 from the other then the third store should be skipped.

Any ideas how to implement this?

```
cout<<endl<<"enter the guns you want from store 1 and press exit to buy from other sstore"<<endl;
cin>>a;

while(a!="exit")
{
    tmp = false;
    for(map<string,int> :: const_iterator it = storeone.begin(); it != storeone.end(); ++it)
    {  
        if(it->first == a)
        {
            b=it->second;
            setfinalguns(a,b);
            cout<<"you bought "<<a<<" for price "<<b<<endl;
            spentmoney(b);
            tmp = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(!tmp)
        cout<<"This gun is not available"<<endl;
    cin>>a;

} 

cout<<"enter the items you want to  from store two and press exit to buy from other store"<<endl;
cin>>c;
while(c!="exit")
{
    tmp = false;
    for(map<string,int> :: const_iterator it = stroretwo.begin(); it != storetwo.end(); ++it)
    {
        if(it->first == c)
        {
            d=it->second;
            setfinalguns(c,d);
            cout<<"you bought "<<c<<" for price "<<d<<endl;
            spentmoney(d);
            tmp = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(!tmp)
        cout<<"Thisgun is not available"<<endl;
    cin>>c;

} 

cout<<"enter the guns you want from store three and press exit to buy from other store"<<endl;
cin>>e;
while(e!="exit")
{
    tmp = false;
    for(map<string,int> :: const_iterator it = storethree.begin(); it != storethree.end(); ++it)
    {
        if(it->first == e)
        {
            f=it->second;
            setfinalguns(e,f);
            cout<<"you bought "<<e<<" for price "<<f<<endl;
            spentmoney(f);
            tmp = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!tmp)
        cout<<"This gun is not available"<<endl;
    cin>>e;
    break;
}
```

Comment: How about something like `if( number_of_guns == 10 ) break;`

Answer (score 0):

Following is the modified code which solves your problem. You just have to add a counter variable (global) which will keep track of the number of guns bought and increment it every time the user buys a gun.

Now, in each iteration of the while loops, check for the value of counter and break if the no. of guns bought is 10.

```
int counter=0;   //This will keep track of number of guns bought
cout<<endl<<"enter the guns you want from store 1 and press exit to buy from other sstore"<<endl;
cin>>a;

while(a!="exit")
{
  if(counter == 10)  // check if user has already bought 10 guns
    break;
  tmp = false;
  for(map<string,int> :: const_iterator it = storeone.begin(); it != storeone.end(); ++it)
  {  
    if(it->first == a)
    {
      b=it->second;
      setfinalguns(a,b);
      cout<<"you bought "<<a<<" for price "<<b<<endl;
      spentmoney(b);
      counter++;
      tmp = true;
      break;
    }
  }
  if(!tmp)
    cout<<"This gun is not available"<<endl;
  cin>>a;

} 

cout<<"enter the items you want to  from store two and press exit to buy from other store"<<endl;
cin>>c;
while(c!="exit")
{
  if(counter == 10)
    break;
  tmp = false;
  for(map<string,int> :: const_iterator it = stroretwo.begin(); it != storetwo.end(); ++it)
  {
    if(it->first == c)
    {
      d=it->second;
      setfinalguns(c,d);
      cout<<"you bought "<<c<<" for price "<<d<<endl;
      spentmoney(d);
      counter++;
      tmp = true;
      break;
    }
  }
  if(!tmp)
    cout<<"Thisgun is not available"<<endl;
  cin>>c;

} 

cout<<"enter the guns you want from store three and press exit to buy from other store"<<endl;
cin>>e;
while(e!="exit")
{
  if(counter == 10)   
    break;
  tmp = false;
  for(map<string,int> :: const_iterator it = storethree.begin(); it != storethree.end(); ++it)
  {
    if(it->first == e)
    {
      f=it->second;
      setfinalguns(e,f);
      cout<<"you bought "<<e<<" for price "<<f<<endl;
      spentmoney(f);
      counter++;
      tmp = true;
      break;
    }
  }
  if (!tmp)
    cout<<"This gun is not available"<<endl;
  cin>>e;
  break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As an explanation to my earlier comment, you can keep a variable to store the number of guns bought.

Then , add a simple if statement like

```
if( number_of_guns == 10 )
   break;
```

at the beginning of your while loops. So to put it simpler, break out from your while loop if the number of guns bought is 10.

Also, to limit the number of guns to 10, you can try something similar to

```
if( number_of_guns > 10 )
      Try_again ;  // or continue
```

This is the info on how to do it, you can try implementing it.